# How to best partition the database in postgres 10

Tags: postgresql, database-partitioning

I have the following table(below), and am planning on adding 250 million rows/day, and I'm trying to partition it by date, was wondering how best to do it in Postgres 10, if there is an automatic way to create a partition on daily basis.

```
CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE public.pricing
(
    uitid character varying(40),
    batch character varying(32),
    scenario character varying(32),
    date date NOT NULL,
    pv double precision,
    ctime real,
    CONSTRAINT pricing_pkey PRIMARY KEY (uitid, batch, scenario, date)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Comment: This answer on dba.se may be of help https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/43947/121084 - Assuming a logical naming scheme for your partitions you should be able to automate it with plpgsql